# How to sort the pagelist items

Tags: sxa

sitecore sxa - I am using paglist for showing product lists with the help of query builder and variants. its not showing proper order list, When in the query builder, I see that sort is an option, its not working in sxa pagelist component. 
Is there any other option to show the product items in orderwise.[image]

Answer (score 3):

It shows based on the sorting on the base folder. in your case. (Product) is the folder, apply the sorting by right-clicking on it, and sort what you need. The default is the Sort by Relevance.

[image]

You can then select based on your criteria from the followings.
[image]

**Sorting it in Query:**

you can use it in the item query:

use for sortorder:

`+template:{227A17F5-E501-4B08-B263-CBAD3DEDEA1C};sort:sortorder`

use for published date:

`+template:{227A17F5-E501-4B08-B263-CBAD3DEDEA1C};sort:published`

Comment: Small adjustment of your answer. it should be `;sort:sortorder` to have same ordering as seen in Content Editor. `Sortorder` field should be used instead of `Published`

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your input. i already tried subitems sorting also. but i am not getting proper items order(default item order)

Comment: i tried this also( sort:sortorder ) . it ll not take the proper order using pagelist with build query.

Comment: Try resetting the sort order on the sub items of product and then check. Try checking in explore mode after published

Comment: @SitecoreSam Thanks this helps me out.